# string value becomes null when it goes to the method .net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Greetings everyone 
**EDIT **
I shortened up the code because it's too much. & the tempdata gets a value from another page i just use it once after i get redirected to this page
& please if you a -1 give an answer i tried multiple things that didn't work

```
string abcd = "";

public ActionResult Index()
{
abcd = @Tempdata["type"].ToString();

//here i call a method to do stuff 

getStuff();
}

public void getStuff()
{
  if (abcd.equals("WORK_PLZ"))
  {
     //stuff here
  }
}
```

my problem is inside `getStuff()` the value of `abcd` is `null` & I don't know why. i tried passing a static value like `OK` before calling the method but it doesn't work

Comment: The Index action method needs a return type!

Comment: Where you assign your TempData?

Comment: `abcd` is null because `TempData["type"]` is null, that one's easy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simple mistake because i was confused.
I have a Model view that communicates with the View to pass all the data but i didn't place the value of the tempdata inside the `abcd` i left null.
I am not sure if the `@` is needed ***before*** `Tempdata` but it works even without
AS

```
model.abcd = @Temdpata["ahh"].ToString();
// & i left abcd decalred in method null THEREFORE Exception
```